# Installation error of Teiid Designer to eclipse

Tags: teiid

while trying install Teiid Designer to eclipse the below message is displaying. it is not allowing me to go forward

```
Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: JBoss Tools Common Core 3.5.2.Final-v20140302-2358-B158 (org.jboss.tools.common.core 3.5.2.Final-v20140302-2358-B158)
        To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 2.3.0
      Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: JBoss Runtime Detection 2.1.0.Final-v20140302-2358-B158 (org.jboss.tools.runtime.core 2.1.0.Final-v20140302-2358-B158)
        To: bundle org.jboss.tools.common.core 3.4.0
      Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: Teiid Designer Runtime 8.6.1.Final-v20150313-2152-B888 (org.teiid.designer.runtime.feature.feature.group 8.6.1.Final-v20150313-2152-B888)
        To: org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core [2.4.0,3.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the installation instructions on [teiid designer download and install page](http://teiiddesigner.jboss.org/designer_summary/downloads.html).

Install into Eclipse 4.5 (Mars)

```
Launch the Help > Install New Software action
Add... the following update site URLs but DO NOT install them. Various dependent plugins required for Teiid Designer will be installed as needed. Make sure “Contact all update sites during install to find required software” is checked.
    http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/targetplatforms/jbosstoolstarget/mars/
    http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/mars/development/updates/integration-stack/earlyaccess
    http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/mars/
Install Teiid Designer 10.0 via update site:
    http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/release/mars/integration-stack/teiiddesigner/10.0.0.Final/
    Click Install button and continue through restarting Eclipse
```